# Javascript Alert Array / Object Value

Tags: javascript

I am getting data from a function that's returning a format like this:

```
var myObject = 
    [
       {
         "name":"myname","receipt":"{"orderid":"2334556"} ...etc
```

I am tryng:

alert(myObject.name);

But that's doing nothing.

How can I alert orderid?

Comment: It's an array, so you should be doing `console.log(myObject[0].name)`

Comment: Note especially the use of `console.log`, and not `alert`

Comment: But I don't want to see it in the log. I want to alert it.

Comment: Then use `alert(myObject[0].name)`. The point is still that the `[` on your second line makes it an array above the object.

Comment: @Satch The log is the conventional place for debug output in this day and age, for a multitude of reasons too numerous to list here. It's worth getting into the habit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go with the other users. It's an array. But there was a `"` before the order bracket that didn't belong there.

```
var myObject = 
[
   {
     "name":"myname","receipt": {"orderid":"2334556"}
   }
   , //array separator
   {
     "name":"othername","receipt": {"orderid":"4656556"}
   }
   //this array contains 2 elements
]

alert(myObject[0].receipt.orderid);
alert(myObject[1].receipt.orderid);
```

I've added another item to this `array` to make clear how this works.

Comment: in your original code the `I` from id was uppercase, while the object has an lowercase `i`.

Answer (score 3):

`myObject` is an array, hence you should do it like:

```
alert(myObject[0].receipt.orderId)
```

Answer (score 1):

`myObject` is an *array*! The data you want is in its first element:

```
alert(myObject[0].receipt.orderId);
```